# How to align tikzpicture beside a question (in the same line)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I mean the question,figure and the answers be in the same rectangular.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks,fontspec,tikz,color}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgf,pgffor,comment,polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\newcommand{\mymk}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[anchor=south west, draw,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=2pt, minimum size=7mm,
    text height=2mm](char){\ensuremath{#1}} ;}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Scheherazade} % Replace 'Simplified Arabic' with a font from your system



\newcommand{\nodear}[1]{node{\begin{Arabic}{#1}\end{Arabic}}}


\begin{document}

    \begin{comment}
    \task[\circled{A}]\hspace{2pt} 
    \task[\circled{B}]\hspace{2pt} 
    \task[\circled{C}]\hspace{2pt} 
    \task[\circled{D}]\hspace{2pt}
    \end{comment}







\begin{Arabic}

    \begin{enumerate}

        \item  في الشكل المجاور؛ إذا كان $m\widehat{AB} = 120\textdegree$ فإنّ قيمة $x$ تساوي \dots

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip[draw] (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
\draw  (0,0) circle(0.5cm);


\end{tikzpicture}



    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task[\circled{A}]\hspace{2pt} 
        \task[\circled{B}]\hspace{2pt} 
        \task[\circled{C}]\hspace{2pt} 
        \task[\circled{D}]\hspace{2pt} 
    \end{tasks}


    \end{enumerate}


\end{Arabic}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this for a question paper exam

Comment: Yes kind of. I am writing some questions to be practiced by others.

Comment: Remove the blank line before `\begin{tikzpicture}`. The blank line makes a new paragraph.

Comment: No, I mean it beside the options just on the left of the A,B,C and D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misinterpreted what your desired result is but you can easily put an `itemize` (or similar) and a `tikzpicture` next to each other using minipages:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks,fontspec,tikz,color}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgf,pgffor,comment,polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\newcommand{\mymk}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[anchor=south west, draw,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=2pt, minimum size=7mm,
    text height=2mm](char){\ensuremath{#1}} ;}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Noto Kufi Arabic}

\newcommand{\nodear}[1]{node{\begin{Arabic}{#1}\end{Arabic}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Arabic}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item في الشكل المجاور؛ إذا كان $m\widehat{AB} = 120\textdegree$ فإنّ قيمة $x$ تساوي \dots
    
      \begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
        \begin{tasks}(2)
            \task[\circled{A}]\hspace{2pt} 
            \task[\circled{B}]\hspace{2pt} 
            \task[\circled{C}]\hspace{2pt} 
            \task[\circled{D}]\hspace{2pt} 
            \task[\circled{E}]\hspace{2pt} 
            \task[\circled{F}]\hspace{2pt} 
        \end{tasks}
      \end{minipage}
      \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth} % use \begin{minipage}[t] for aligning the picture to the top
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \clip[draw] (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
          \draw  (0,0) circle(0.5cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

Which yields (I did not bother to figure out the font handling):

[image: output of the above code]

Comment: Hint

A mistake that is often made is, there is a blank line between the \end{minipage} and \begin{minipage} left. Then the pages are no longer together. Source:
https://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-minipage.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`mulitcol`](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf) package and place the tikzpicture and tasks environment inside a 2 columned block. A few helpful tipps can be found in this [overleaf tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multiple_columns).

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks,fontspec,tikz,color}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgf,pgffor,comment,polyglossia}

\usepackage{multicol}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\newcommand{\mymk}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[anchor=south west, draw,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=2pt, minimum size=7mm,
    text height=2mm](char){\ensuremath{#1}} ;}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Noto Kufi Arabic} % Replace 'Simplified Arabic' with a font from your system



\newcommand{\nodear}[1]{node{\begin{Arabic}{#1}\end{Arabic}}}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{comment}
    \task[\circled{A}]\hspace{2pt} 
    \task[\circled{B}]\hspace{2pt} 
    \task[\circled{C}]\hspace{2pt} 
    \task[\circled{D}]\hspace{2pt}
    \end{comment}
    
    \begin{Arabic}
        
        \begin{enumerate}
            
            \item  في الشكل المجاور؛ إذا كان $m\widehat{AB} = 120\textdegree$ فإنّ قيمة $x$ تساوي \dots
                
                \begin{multicols}{2}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \clip[draw] (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
                        \draw  (0,0) circle(0.5cm);
    
                    \end{tikzpicture}
    
                    \begin{tasks}(2)
                        \task[\circled{A}]\hspace{2pt} 
                        \task[\circled{B}]\hspace{2pt} 
                        \task[\circled{C}]\hspace{2pt} 
                        \task[\circled{D}]\hspace{2pt} 
                    \end{tasks}
                \end{multicols}
        \end{enumerate}
    
    \end{Arabic}    
\end{document}
```

[image: output]